# Callback function inside datatable applied on rownames is not working

Tags: javascript, r, datatables-1.10

I am trying to add JS components into my datatable in R which will allow showing the value of a rowname inside the table by tooltip and  doubleclick.
That's the code which i was using for the same purpose but with the table body

```working one`````

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$body(tags$script(HTML("
                                      function createCustomAlert(text) {
                                       url = '';
                                       title = 'Value';
                                       w = 300;
                                       h = 400;
                                       
                                       var dualScreenLeft = getFirstNumber(window.screenLeft, screen.left),
                                       dualScreenTop = getFirstNumber(window.screenTop, screen.top),
                                       width = getFirstNumber(window.innerWidth, document.documentElement.clientWidth, screen.width),
                                       height = getFirstNumber(window.innerHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight, screen.height),
                                       left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft,
                                       top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop,
                                       newWindow = window.open(url, title, getSpecs());
                                       
                                       
                                       // Puts focus on the newWindow
                                       if (window.focus) {
                                       newWindow.focus();
                                       }
                                       
                                       newWindow.document.write('<p id=Page></p>');
                                       text = '<title> Value </title>' + text ;
                                       return newWindow.document.getElementById('Page').innerHTML = text;

                                       function getSpecs() {
                                       return 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left;
                                       }
                                       
                                       function getFirstNumber() {
                                       for(var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
                                       var value = arguments[i];
                                       
                                       if (typeof value === 'number') {
                                       return value;
                                       }
                                       }
                                       }
                                       
                                       }
                                       " ))),
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$table<-DT::renderDataTable({
    table<-data.table("a"=c(1,2,3,4),"b"=c(2,3,6,7),"loooooonnnnnnngggggggg sssssssttttttrrrriiiiiinnnngggg"=c(2,3,45,7))
    corTable<-cor(table)
    datatable(corTable ,
              callback=JS(
                "table.on('dblclick.dt','tbody td', function() {",
                "let Row = table.row(this).data();",
                "let column_num = parseInt( $(this).index() );",
                "let text = Row[column_num]",
                paste0("if(text.length > ",5,"){"),
                "createCustomAlert(text)",
                "}",
                "})"
              ),
              options=list(
                rowCallback=JS(
                  "function(tbody,data){",
                  "let tbodyText = data",
                  paste0("if(tbodyText[0].length > ",5,"){"),
                  "$('td',tbody).attr('title',tbodyText)",
                  "}",
                  "}"
                ),
                columnDefs = list(list(
                  targets  = 0,
                  render = JS(
                    "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
                    paste0("return type === 'display' && data!==null && data.length > ",5," ?"),
                    paste0("'<span>' + data.substr(0, ",5,") + '...</span>' : data;"),
                    "}")
                )),
                pageLength = 10,ordering=T,searching = FALSE,lengthChange=FALSE
              )
    )
  })
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

``````````````````````I am trying``````````````````````````````````

```
table<-data.table("a"=c(1,2,3,4),"b"=c(2,3,6,7),"loooooonnnnnnngggggggg sssssssttttttrrrriiiiiinnnngggg"=c(2,3,45,7))
corTable<-cor(table)
    datatable(corTable ,
                      callback=JS(
                        "table.on('dblclick.dt','tbody td', function() {",
                        "let Row = table.row(this).data();",
                        "let column_num = parseInt( $(this).index() );",
                        "let text = Row[column_num]",
                        paste0("if(text.length > ",5,"){"),
                        "createCustomAlert(text)",
                        "}",
                       "})"
                      ),
                      options=list(
                      rowCallback=JS(
                        "function(tbody,data){",
                        "let tbodyText = data",
                        paste0("if(tbodyText[0].length > ",5,"){"),
                        "$('td',tbody).attr('title',tbodyText)",
                        "}",
                        "}"
                      ),
                        columnDefs = list(list(
                          targets  = 0,
                          render = JS(
                            "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
                            paste0("return type === 'display' && data!==null && data.length > ",5," ?"),
                            paste0("'<span>' + data.substr(0, ",5,") + '...</span>' : data;"),
                            "}")
                        )),
                        pageLength = 10,ordering=T,searching = FALSE,lengthChange=FALSE
                      )
            )
```

`end`
The createcustomealert function is identified in the UI script in our shiny app and it is the following.

```
    function createCustomAlert(text) {
                                           url = '';
                                           title = 'Value';
                                           w = 300;
                                           h = 400;
                                           
                                           var dualScreenLeft = getFirstNumber(window.screenLeft, screen.left),
                                           dualScreenTop = getFirstNumber(window.screenTop, screen.top),
                                           width = getFirstNumber(window.innerWidth, document.documentElement.clientWidth, screen.width),
                                           height = getFirstNumber(window.innerHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight, screen.height),
                                           left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft,
                                           top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop,
                                           newWindow = window.open(url, title, getSpecs());
                                           
                                           
                                           // Puts focus on the newWindow
                                           if (window.focus) {
                                           newWindow.focus();
                                           }
                                           
                                           newWindow.document.write('<p id=Page></p>');
                                           text = '<title> Value </title>' + text ;
                                           return newWindow.document.getElementById('Page').innerHTML = text;
    
                                           function getSpecs() {
                                           return 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left;
                                           }
                                           
                                           function getFirstNumber() {
                                           for(var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
                                           var value = arguments[i];
                                           
                                           if (typeof value === 'number') {
                                           return value;
                                           }
                                           }
                                           }
                                           
                                           }
```